# LinearLayoutManager vs GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

I don't have any coding question or something, I had this application that populates (from a webservice) a gridlayoutmanager recyclerview of 2 rows and now the client wants it to be a List. I just want to ask which is better for the performance setting the number of rows  of the gridlayoutmanager to 1, or switching to LinearLayoutmanager.
regards,

Comment: No need to use GridLayoutManager if you have 1 column.

Comment: yeah i know i switched to linearlayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's more elegant using `LinearLayoutManager` if you have one row, but for performance it's same.

Answer (score 1):

**LinearLayoutManager :**

- LinearLayoutManager is similar to old ListView concept.
- it's fully occupy the row they not bother but each item Text size or
  image width height etc.

**GridLayoutManager :**

- Using GirdLayoutManager you can split each row more than one item.
- You can add 3 in row or 4 row or etc but each row each item width and
  height are same like below,

[image]

- Grid View shows symmetric items in view.

  Using GridLayoutManager you can also done alternative row count like odd row's are 2 items and even row's 4 items by using setSpanSizeLookup.

**Finally myself main difference using GridLayoutManager you done better and innovative UI in Android.**

[image]